# System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100000f

Tags: asp.net, linux, mono

I get this error running a sample asp.net 5 application on ubuntu 14.04LTS.

after a successful dnu restore command, running dnx kestrel command returns the following error: System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100000f.

I tried different versions of mono still the same error. I noticed also a  difference between kestrel versions in my project.lock.json file(could it be it).
on the browser it returned an internal server error!
I can post the file if needed.
appreciate it!