# Getting "Could not resolve type with token 0100028 from typeref" from BrowserCapabilitiesFactory in Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I am currently building a small embedded web server using Mono (using MonoDevelop on Linux). While trying to detect the browser type using a recommendation from a code example, I've ran into a problem. The **program compiles correctly** but the code below results in the program crashing when entering the function where it is declared:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;

[...]

var l_caps = new HttpBrowserCapabilities
{
  Capabilities = new Hashtable { { string.Empty, p_http_context.Request.UserAgent } }
};

var l_capsFactory = new BrowserCapabilitiesFactory();

l_capsFactory.ConfigureBrowserCapabilities(new NameValueCollection(), l_caps);
```

The code above was supposed to parse the user agent string for the headers of a request, (present on p_http_context.Request.UserAgent), allowing the capabilities of the client's browser to be exposed to the server-side in the l_caps object. However, if the following line is present in the code, as soon as the program flow reaches the function, it raises the exception described below. Commenting the line avoids the exception but only because it removes the functionality:

```cs
var l_capsFactory = new BrowserCapabilitiesFactory();
```

The error obtained is as follows:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000028 from typeref (expected class > 'System.Web.Configuration.BrowserCapabilitiesFactory' in assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
>    at Server.Context.onNewRequest (System.Object p_origin, >Server.Listener+NewContextEventArgs p_args) [0x000b9] in Context.cs:143

I do not have any NuGet package. I am **not** using ASP.Net, it's a pure console application (daemon) using HttpListener. As such, the conventional methods for obtaining the browser capabilities are not available (namely Request.Browser isn't available in this context).

I have tried the following:

- different versions of the libraries involved;
- cleaning the solution;
- removing all bin and obj folders from the solution and subprojects;
- building under both debug and release modes;
- reinstalling;
- combinations of the above.

I have also searched for solutions in several similar problems both on Stack Overflow and other platforms, but none of the solutions for those problems, when found, had any positive influence on this specific situation. Examples:

- [System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000115](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51960070/system-typeloadexception-could-not-resolve-type-with-token-01000115)
- [Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100003b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343532/unhandled-exception-system-typeloadexception-could-not-resolve-type-with-token)
- [Could not resolve type with token 0100000f](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163887/could-not-resolve-type-with-token-0100000f)
- [System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100000f](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604946/system-typeloadexception-could-not-resolve-type-with-token-0100000f)
- [xamarin : System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42338168/xamarin-system-typeloadexception-could-not-resolve-type-with-token-01000017)
- [System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 0100000c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971365/system-typeloadexception-could-not-resolve-type-with-token-0100000c)
- [System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752764/system-typeloadexception-could-not-resolve-type-with-token-01000019)

Versions:

- Mono 5.18.1.3
- .Net Framework 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2
- C# version: all from 5 to 7.3
- MonoDevelop 7.8.2
- Linux Ubuntu 18.04

As an attempt to crudely diagnose this, I also grepped the mono libraries in /usr/lib/mono for the "BrowserCapabilitiesFactory" token, yielding positive results.

Does anyone have any suggestions on solving for further diagnosing this situation?

Am I missing any additional assembly reference in the project?

Comment: You are using http so I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and get actual return item from the sniffer.  I would check to see if the status is 200 OK or someting else.  There are two http modes 1) 1.0 which is stream mode 2) 1.1 which is chunk mode.  I suspect you are using 1.1 and only getting one response and the connection is timing out due to not sending next chunk message.

Comment: Your response **has absolutely nothing** to do with the problem at hand. Besides the connection is working fine, the program only started getting that exception once I added the line. HTTP is working fine and since the program *is the server*, it is the program that actually sends the status. Besides, the status is only sent **after** the browser information is received.

Comment: There are tons of similar issues and no one has been working on fixes. So in all cases you should consider switching to .NET Core, which is in active development. You should know that Mono is going away when .NET 5 ships in 2020.

Comment: That would imply recreating the project from scratch and copying the old sources, which may not have everything available in .NET Core.
I also did read those news and my post predates those news. In any case, switching to .NET Core may not be feasible at the moment.

Comment: @LexLi: From the [interview to Richard Lander on The Register](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/05/16/will_net_5_really_unify_microsoft_development_stack/):

_Despite this, Mono will not go away, he told The Reg. "We'll invest less engineering effort in Mono. It will mostly flow into .NET 5.0. The community will probably invest less engineering effort and gradually workloads will move onto .NET 5.0. But we're not going to try to kill the project. There's still big applications that depend on Mono and may never port to use .NET 5.0."_

So, it means it's definitely not going away in 2020.

Comment: An open source project dies hardly, but if you are seriously a user/developer, you should move away from inactive ones (or scenarios they no longer cover). So today it means "ASP.NET 4.x on Mono" (your case) or "MonoDevelop on Windows/Mac", and tomorrow it means more technologies based on Mono.

Comment: @LexLi: as clearly stated in the original post above: _"I am not using ASP.Net"_. So, "ASP.NET 4.x on Mono" is not the case at all. It is a standalone console application using HttpListener. Using .Net Core has, so far, proven unfruitful despite attempts. It is a .Net application running on Mono for Linux, developed in MonoDevelop.

Comment: Hi. Same issue with class `System.Web.Instrumentation.PageInstrumentationService` token 01000039. The class look to exist in my "mono/4.6.2-api/System.Web.dll". No idea how to fix.

Comment: It seems more and more likely that those elements aren't actually implemented in classic Mono. I have since moved the entire project to dotNet Core and haven't had those issues anymore.